# dynamic select in VBA-excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a copy & paste job basically. 
I want to bring over data from one document into another. 
I want to find the data based on the content in a cell which is not always in the same place and I want to select values below that cell up to the next blank row.

For example: Select all cells in a range below the cell that says "CURRENT MONTH" until the next row that is blank.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub getCurrentMonth()

'get the current month data
Windows("File1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B1000").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "CURRENT MONTH") Then
N = Cells(7, 2).End(xlDown).Select
Range("B7:AD" & N).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Automation.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Else
MsgBox ("No data for Current Month Found")
End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What is your specific question? I suggest recording the use of the Find feature and then exploring it, and adding to it.

Comment: Or is the value "CURRENT MONTH" always in the same column? And is it always the first occupied cell of the column?

Comment: It is always in the same column, but it is not always the first occupied cell in that column. It moves up and down based on the data that is printed above it.

Comment: If CURRENT MONTH is found is the data in a contiguous block/table below the cell? With no blank cells in col B of the table (below it)?

Comment: Use `Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(What:="CURRENT MONTH", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1,0)` to retrieve the cell (it looks in the entire column for a cell whose text is exactly equal to "CURRENT MONTH"). Then use `Range(rngCell.Address & ":" & rngCell.Address.End(xlDown).Address).Copy` to copy the range.

Comment: No the current month data runs until a blank cell. The cell after that blank cell shows "NEXT MONTH" & next month data follows.

Comment: @BrownishMonster this seemed to only return the line with "Current Month" in it.
 Windows("File1.xlsm").Activate
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(What:="CURRENT MONTH", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0)
       Selection.Copy
    Windows("Automation.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. It assumes that all data under Current Month is contiguous, based on your description. If it's not, let me know and I will edit.

```
Option Explicit

Sub getCurrentMonth()

    'get the current month data
    With Workbooks("File1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim foundIt As Range
        Set foundIt = .Range("B1:B1000").Find("CURRENT MONTH", lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not foundIt Is Nothing Then

            Set foundIt = .Range(foundIt.Offset(1,-1), foundIt.End(xlDown)) 'from column A and down
            Set foundIt = foundIt.Resize(foundIt.Rows.Count,29) 'from column A to AD
            Workbooks("Automation.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(foundIt.Rows.Count, foundIt.Columns.Count).Value = foundIt.Value

        Else

            MsgBox ("No data for Current Month Found")

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked to get one column, thanks! How would I get the entire row selected and copied for each?

Comment: @hellosimoni - do you want the entire row? Or just rows with data? If just rows with data how many columns will it be? Or is it a contiguous set of columns (with no blanks cells until the end of the data set)?

Comment: Yes, I need the entire row for each row of data below "CURRENT MONTH" the columns are contiguous. It goes from Column A-AD but some columns are hidden, which I don't want returned.

Comment: @hellosimoni - *some columns are hidden which I don't want returned* - if you want to skip certain columns of the data this make it **much more complex**. It also should have been noted in your initial question. How many columns do you not want to show and which columns are they?

Comment: Sorry I forgot. We can start with just returning the entire row. I have another sub that already prints only my unhidden columns which I should be able to figure it out. But Column A, F, G, M, P, Q, R, S, T, U, W, X are hidden The code that I use to get the past month's data is below. This doesn't work for the CURRENT MONTH because the cell where that text is moves based on how many rows of past month data there are.

Comment: Windows("File1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "PAST MONTH") Then
    N = Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    Range("B4:AD" & N).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Automation.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

Comment: @hellosimoni - I grabbed data to column AD since that was in your code. If it doesn't work *exactly* fiddle with offsets and resize arguments to match perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I learned a lot. I appreciate it!